# Calling Jersey from Angular2

Tags: json, rest, angular, jersey, jax-rs

I'm beggining to play with Angular2. I have developed a basic RESTful API using Jersey. I tested it and it works fine (with browser and SOAP UI). This is the code:

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public TwoWordsMessage getMessage() {
    TwoWordsMessage message = new TwoWordsMessage();
    message.setFirstWord("hello");
    message.setSecondWord("world");
    return message;        
  }
```

I'm tryng to call the service from an Angular2 app:

```
    this.http.request(this.url).subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.message = res.json();
    });
```

I can see (debbuging) that "getMessage" method is called and it returns the TwoWordsMessage object but the Angular2 application never gets it. The same code with the url http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 works fine.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what's your RESTful response look like?

Comment: seems like ng2 server it's waiting for the response or doesn't know how to handle it. It never gets to `code`this.message = res.json();`code`

Comment: Did you check the developer console? Any errors? Maybe CORS error?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the http request inside a component or a service? Does a function or method fire off the http request?

Also, can you see if there are errors coming back from the response? The `subscribe` method can take three functions as parameters, first one being on success, second on error, third on completion. If there's an error in the AJAX call (400s, 500s, etc), your code would never be able to handle it. Try this:

```
this.http.request(this.url).subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.message = res.json();
}, (error) => {
   console.warn(error)
});
```

and see what is spit out. To further debug, you can even use the `.do()` method on the Observable:

```
this.http.request(this.url)
  .do((res: Response) => console.log(res)) // or other stuff
  .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    this.message = res.json();
});
```

The `.do()` method will execute an arbitrary function with the response without actually affecting it.

If not, you could also try changing the http call to `http.get()`. I don't think that's the problem, but the Angular docs do not state what method is defaulted to with `http.request()` (although I would be almost certain it's a GET).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. It's a CORS problem.

The console showed the error:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource"

I changed the resource method like this:

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getMessage() {
    TwoWordsMessage message = new TwoWordsMessage();
    message.setFirstWord("hello");
    message.setSecondWord("world");
    return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").entity(message).build();        
  }
```

You can find useful information here:

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/